# Dismiss keyboard on scroll?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have textfield in app. This open keyboard automatic when tap on textfield. But when scroll down on list (firebaseAnimatedList) behind it keyboard is not dismiss. This not normal and is big problem on iOS because cannot press back button to dismiss.

Anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

```dart
NotificationListener(
  onNotification: (t) {
    if (t is UserScrollNotification) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    }
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(),
    itemCount: items.length,
  ),
);
```

Attaching a `ScrollListener` didn't work for me because Android uses `ClampingScrollPhysics` and it will only receive the scroll event if the ListView items are longer than the parent. However, a `NotificationListener` will receive all events bubbled up including `UserScrollNotification`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use keyboardDismissBehavior.

```
return ListView.builder(
        keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following code in your lists scroll listener.

`FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I can implement with onTap() and GestureDetector. But no know to add to call on scroll. I am use animatedlist. Where to add so when scroll animated list keyboard is dismiss?

Answer (score 0):

This is what gives you the desired effect:

```
NotificationListener(
 onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {

   if (scrollInfo is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
     if (scrollInfo.scrollDelta >= 20.0)      {
       FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      }
     }

    },
 child: new FirebaseAnimatedList ...)
```